# detecting welcome message discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When a person joins a server in discord, discord, by default, sends a message saying something like "I hope you brought pizza, **user**!" I want to detect these messages using discord.js, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to detect that message. It's just a notification. The *message* is not actually sent by anyone.

Comment: interesting, how would you detect a notification then? :p

Comment: As I said. I don't think it's possible. However, I am also happy to be taught otherwise.

Comment: @Behemoth It is actually a message that is created by the user who joined. Check my answer for details.

Comment: Ohh awesome! Does that mean the welcome notification is treated like a normal *message*? So you could do things like `message.content` as well?

Comment: @Behemoth Unfortunately, the `message.content` is empty on this type of message. But other properties and methods work, such as [`reply`](https://i.imgur.com/7GZcWqF.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Message#type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=type) property to determine if it is a welcome message. The type will be `GUILD_MEMBER_JOIN` in that case.

---

```js
if (message.type === 'GUILD_MEMBER_JOIN') {
    message.channel.send('Welcome to the server!')
}
```